# Question regarding the syntax of SGESV in Fortran

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am a bit confused on this subroutine. I have read the documentation but I am a bit confused what exactly the IPIV vector does and how exactly I set my leading dimension. I read that the leading dimension helps to find the starting point for the matrix elements in each successive column of the array. For example lets say we want to solve

```
Ax = B
```

where

```
integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(6,37)
real(kind=sp),dimension(:,:),intent(inout) :: A
real(kind=sp),dimension(:),intent(inout) :: B
integer, dimension(10) :: IPIV
```

where sp is for single precision which I have set in my main program
and the dimensions are

```
A(10,10)
B(10)
```

which are set in my main program and passed to this subroutine
Should I set my subroutine as

```
integer :: n,INFO
n = size(A,1)


IPIV = 0
call SGESV(n,n,A,2*n,IPIV,B,2*n,INFO)
```

or

```
call SGESV(n,n,A,n,IPIV,B,n,INFO)
```

and for IPIV I should just create a vector of size 10 and initialize it with zeros?

---

edit : I have used

```
call sgesv(n, n, A, n, ipiv, B, n, INFO)
```

as proposed as well but I get a segmentation error Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

I have printed the matrix sizes and they are correct which are the size of the matrix A is 100 and the size of the vector is 10

Edit2 : So in my main I have a loop which inside my loop it calculates a matrix of A (10,10) and a vector B(10) at each iteration. Then I call my subroutine to solve the system

```
call solver(A,B)
```

However I get the segmentation error which I do not understand since the dimensions are correct. (To check it I printed the size of the matrix and the vector and commented out the call to my subroutine and they are 100 and 10)

Perhaps I should make my matrices allocatable? But I do not see a problem with that since at each iteration I calculate the matrix and the vector though a series of calculations and overwrite them.

Basically I declare the matrix and the vector as follows

```
   real(sp) , dimension (10) :: B
   real(sp) , dimension (10,10) :: A
```

then inside my loop a series of calculations are performed to fill them with values
and then I call my subroutine
and then repeat with new values

Comment: You should really show your declarations of A and B in code, not in words.

Comment: Hello thank you for replying! I edited to show you my declarations now!

Comment: `IPIV` should return the pivoting order (array of indices) .

Comment: Though A and B are dummy arguments (with intent(inout)), are they contiguous in actual calls?

Comment: @Alex please provide a fully-functional [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. that includes a *program* .

Comment: @Alex You wrote `B(5)` and `real(sp) , dimension (10) :: B` and "size..vector..10". 10 would be correct but 5 not. which is it?

Comment: @Alex could you include the error message in your question? it might be helpful.

Comment: @Hey Jack sorry I meant B(10) . I will edit it right now . And the error I got is Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference. From my understanding it tries to access data in a memory that is already deleted or not there?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old interface to lapack. Note my lower answer for the modern/generic routine.

---

**Old interface**
You would call it like

```pascal
call sgesv(n, n, A, n, ipiv, B, n, info)
```

Reasoning:

- leading dimensions are `n` and not `2n`
- `ipiv` is an output variable s.t. you dont need to initialize it with 0

---

**Modern interface: LAPACK95**
It is alot easier to just use the modern interfaces which provide generic calls as such

```pascal
call gesv(A, B, ipiv=ipiv, info=info)
```

You dont need to specify the data types (e.g. no more `sgesv`) nor matrix dimensions.

Make sure that you need to use the appropriate module

```pascal
use lapack95
```

Comment: The problem is, I am trying the old interface with exactly the same syntax as you posted but I get a segmentation fault -->       Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Comment: @Alex please add your [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question as well as the error message. then we might be able to tell you more.

Comment: I will add them in the main question right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of calling `gesv` the generic Lapack95 equivalent (and much simpler) of `sgesv` and `dgesv`.

```
subroutine test_lapack95(n)
use BLAS95
use LAPACK95
use f95_precision
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: n
real(float), allocatable :: A(:,:), LU(:,:)
real(float), allocatable :: b(:), x(:)
integer, allocatable :: ipiv(:)

allocate(A(n,n))
allocate(b(n))
allocate(ipiv(n))

! Fill values in A and b
call prepare_values(n, A, b)
        
LU = A
x = b
call gesv(LU,x,ipiv)
! Solve to A*x=b, for x

end subroutine
```

don't worry about the helper function `prepare_values`, it just fill in `A` and `b`.

Comment: you should try to keep code as short as possible. this will help to highlight the important lines.